# Using css class in php script

Tags: php, css

I used [enjoycss](http://enjoycss.com) to create some css components and then get the codes. For a button, I got

```
.mybutton-css {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #018dc4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: normal 16px/normal Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #0199d9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(15,73,168,0.66) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

However, it differs from what I see in the tutorials as they use `.button` but I don't see that. I also don't know how to call that! should I create a file named `mybutton-css.txt`? In `test.php`, I have

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Hello </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        print( "hello world" );
        <input type="button" class="mybutton-css" value="Load File" />
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really need to start with some basic tutorials. Nothing in your example requires PHP at all, and you'll have one big syntax error from the code you posted. You get to pick your class names - it can be `.button`, `.mybutton-css`, or `.whatever-the-hell-you-want-it-to-be`.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, what is actually happening, and where your confusion is coming from. Also, as this appears to be a CSS issue, why do you have PHP code in the middle? (By the way, your <input> tag should go outside the PHP, not inside)

Comment: (Another side note: stop using that generator. It's spewing a bunch of pointless and needlessly complex crap into your CSS that's likely confusing you immensely. Start with some really simple CSS rules to learn.)

Comment: Well I will add more PHP code. This is a start point for adding a button and play with it!

Comment: @ceejayoz: I do agree with you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve with PHP, but - based on your demo - you don't need any PHP at all.

You just need the following CSS and HTML :

```css
.mybutton-css {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #018dc4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: normal 16px/normal Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #0199d9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(15,73,168,0.66) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
hello world
<input type="button" class="mybutton-css" value="Load File" />
```

For a real world application, you would typically put your CSS in a css file that is named something like `style.css`.

Then, you add your CSS with the following tag in the head of your HTML document :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

You would put this in the body of your HTML document :

```
hello world
<input type="button" class="mybutton-css" value="Load File" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should paste your generated CSS code inside a `<style>` tag in your `<head>` tag

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .mybutton-css {
               //Your generated CSS code here
            }
        </style>
```

Even better, you should create a `style.css` file and import it in your HTML with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
```